# Can I create a macro or shortuct for a step of XPath in XQuery?

Tags: xml, xpath, macros, xquery

Do we have Macros in XQuery?

If yes, could you please give an example of their usage.

I have the following code

```
let $x := //price/ancestor::*
```

Can I someway, using macros or other things write it as follows:

```
let $x := //price/outward
```

So, the `outward` should mean `ancestor::*`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XQuery does not know such macros, you could of course use any preprocessor to do such things.

But I'd rather define a function for this:

```
declare function local:outward($context as item()) {
  $context/ancestor-or-self::*
};
```

Functions can also be applied in axis steps (remember to pass the current context `.`):

```
let $xml := document { <foo><bar><batz>quix</batz></bar></foo> }
return $xml/foo/bar/local:outward(.)
```

You can even go on as it would be a "normal" XPath expression:

```
let $xml := document { <foo id="foo"><bar id="bar"><batz id="batz">quix</batz></bar></foo> }
return $xml/foo/bar/local:outward(.)/@id
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Jens answer (using a function)...  If the goal is not only to have syntactic sugar, but at some point to let someone "configure" the navigation to take place, you can combine Jens answer with function items.  In XPath (and XQuery) 3.0, a function can be represented by a function item.  A function item can be assigned to a variable, and can be used to call the function it "points to."

```
declare function local:outward($context as node()) {
   $context/ancestor-or-self::*
};

declare function local:inward($context as node()) {
   $context/descendant-or-self::*
};

declare function local:id($doc as node(), $axis as function(*)) {
   (: note how we "call the variable $axis" :)
   $doc/foo/bar/$axis(.)/@id
};

declare variable $input :=
   document {
      <foo id="foo"><bar id="bar"><batz id="batz"/></bar></foo> };

(: find the @id attributes in ancestors :)
local:id($input, local:outward#1)
,
(: find the @id attributes in descendants :)
local:id($input, local:inward#1)
```